# Where can I find the Generated Servlet from JSP from tomcat:run?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

Before, I'm using the server in eclipse to deploy/run my webapp and I can easily find the generated servlets in `...metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/...`. Now that I moved to m2e and use tomcat:run to deploy and run my webapp, i'm wondering where can I find the generated servlets?

Comment: ok got it `target\tomcat\work\localEngine\localhost\...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference `target\tomcat\work\localEngine\localhost\<name related to webapp>\org\apache\jsp` is the location of the generated servlets.

Answer (score 4):

The generated java classes of the corresponding jsp files should be available in the following path of your tomcat directory. The following example is taken from a Linux machine.

```
{TOMCAT_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/{app_name}/org/apache/jsp/
```

Comment: Just to clarify, did you use m2e(maven plugin for eclipse) and use eclipse maven build to invoke tomcat:run?

Comment: May be you are right as you are running inside eclipse using m2e. However my answer was for when deploying on separately running tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

The generated java servlets of corresponding jsp files should be found in following path of tomcat directory, Following taken from Cent OS machine

```
    {TOMCAT_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/manager/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Project_Location_from_eclipse.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\OurProject Name\org\apache\jsp